# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined at C:\....\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:148:86

Tags: angular

I am unable to run my angular project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWSop.png)

**Below are the versions I am using in my project:** 
Angular CLI: 12.1.3
Node: 12.18.1
Package Manager: npm 6.14.5
OS: win32 x64

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^11.1.1"
}


"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1101.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.1.2",
    "@types/d3": "^6.7.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/ramda": "github:types/npm-ramda#dist",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "mv": "^2.1.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "replace-in-file": "^6.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.2"
}
```

I tried uninstalling node modules and package.lock and did npm cache clean..
Tried uninstalling angular cli and reinstalled
Nothing worked for me
Please help me if anyone facing similar issue.

Comment: Hi Rakasha and welcome to StackOverflow!
Please provide the exact command you used to start the build.

Answer (score 0):

can only speculate w/o knowing the exact command used to build, the other parts of `package.json` and the content of `angular.json` but I think **you are using the angular 12 cli to build an angular 11 project**.

try building like this

```
npm run build
```

that should use the locally installed version of the angular cli (11) instead of the globally installed version (12).